# <Button Text="{Binding .}"/> doesn't work as intended

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, binding

I have a CollectionView where the ItemsSource is bound with a List. The contents of this list should be displayed in the Text of the Button. To do this I use Text={Binding .}.

When the page loads, I get empty buttons with no text. If I then remove the `.` and retype it in the {Binding .}, the text will appear in my buttons.

Can someone explain this to me or explain what I'm doing wrong?

**.xaml**

```
<StackLayout>
            <CollectionView x:Name="ItemsListView" ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentQuizItem.Answers}" SelectionMode="None">
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackLayout >
                            <Button Text="{Binding .}" Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewmodel:TakeQuizPageViewModel}}, Path=AnswerClickedCommand}" Style="{StaticResource AnswerButton}"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
        </StackLayout>
```

Comment: what is the type of `CurrentQuizItem.Answers`?

Comment: @Jason It is a List<string> which is used to preview text in the buttons

Comment: that should work.  You might try disabling Hot Reload to see if that is causing a problem

Comment: @Jason I did that already but it didn't work

Comment: @Jason Do you have something else to propose?

Comment: Depends on how/when you initialize your `CurrentQuizItem.Answers`, it may should be of type `ObservableCollection<string>` not `List<string>`

Comment: @Cfun Also tried it but had the same effect.. i still get empty text in my buttons

Comment: could you share you code also for more clarity ?

Comment: I fixed it by changing the List<string> to List<Answer> where Answer is a model with one property inside, which is a string. Instead of binding with dot, i bind with the property in the model. This way it works!

Comment: Great that you got it to work! If you add that solution as "Your Answer" below, then everyone will know that you no longer need help - without reading all the way to the end of these comments :)